# Rearranging 6-class model to 6 2-class models. Will it give any improvement?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have a SVM model consisting of 6 classes and 19 features. It works well, 95% accuracy.
I'm evaluating, how to get the last 5%. My idea is to create other models with other features, train instances.
Another idea is to rearrange the existing model from 6 classes to 6 models each with 2 classes, where one class is positive and the other 5 classes are negative. The features will remain the same. Will it bring any new classification results, or is it just a redundant model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My idea is to create other models with other features, train
>   instances.

Yes, it's a good idea. Check performance of other models on your data.

> Another idea is to rearrange the existing model from 6 classes to 6
>   models each with 2 classes, where one class is positive and the other
>   5 classes are negative.

Since SVM is a binary classifier. A multiclass SVM classifier internally uses either [One-Vs-All or One-vs-One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification). What you are suggesting is one-vs-all. Since libsvm uses One-vs-One technique. you can use [one-vs-all](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f808) but this usually doesn't increase accuracy performance as one-vs-one uses more number of classifier.

Comment: OK, thank you for the links! I may have overlooked something essential.

Answer (score 1):

SVM is only actually capable of doing binary classification.  The multi-class adaptation uses several models and votes on what the class should be in a one-vs-one scheme.

Quick example:

```
class1 vs class2 
class2 vs class3
class1 vs class3
```

would all be used in a 3-class SVM, then the models would vote on what class a observation should be. one-vs-all is another popular way to use SVM in a multiple classification scenario.  To answer your question, that's already kind of what is going on behind the scenes.  It is possible building even more models could help improve on your accuracy by a small margin, so its worth a shot if you're bored and want to see if it helps or not